# Best practices for merging and testing, should we test more?

Tags: git, testing

```
git version 1.8.1.4
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
```

Hello,

I use git as my respostery and everytime there is a new feature that needs to be added or a bug that needs to be fixed. I create a new branch from our most stable one, and I proceed to add a new feature or fix the bug. Normally, I can be working on many new features and bug fixes at the same time. So I could have many git branches.

This creates conflicts with the testers, as they don't want to test the new features or the bug fixes. What they would like me to do is merge everything together once I have finished them, into the stable branch and then they test everything together in one go. This is good for the testers, as they just test once.

However, what I would like them to do:

```
1) Test the new feature or bug fix on that branch.
2) Once it has passed I will merge it to the stable branch.
3) Once is has been merged into the stable branch test it again to make sure it still works .
```

This means the tester have to test more and they don't like doing that.

The problem is, merging everything together before testing it can create more bugs. As I will be merging an untested branch into a stable one. And if I am merging a few branches into a stable one this can cause the stable one to have more bugs.

Questions:

```
1) I am just wondering is my concept correct or are the testers correct?
2) Is there any offical or standard document that I can use to show them that everything should be tested first before merging?
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1):

There really is no absolute right or wrong to either argument. Personally, I would take a bit of a middle ground (and have done just this in other places with similar requirements for testing).  I would branch the most stable branch into a topic branch (features_and_fixes, or something else similarly clever).  Branch off of **that** branch for each individual new feature or bug.  This has one benefit that may not seem clear at first.  You are branching off of a common base for all of your individual features and fixes. That should make merging changes back in much, much easier.

Once you have tested each individual feature or fix (since I assume your testers are really validators and that you test your own code thoroughly), then you can merge back to the common topic branch. Test you changes again once each new feature or fix is merged, fixing merge-related bugs as you find them.

Once all is good, then you can merge the whole smash into the original stable branch.  if the merge causes problems, one commit puts you right back where you started.  That will mean a bit more testing for you (since you will have to test your own code twice), but you will also be able to merge just about any number of changes quickly and safely. You are one revert away from undoing whatever chaos a large number of changes caused.  That is how I would it...